# python pandas データフレームにおける各要素をリストではなくしたい

Tags: python, pandas

ほぼ初心者なので、見当違いのこと言ってるかもしれませんがご教授よろしくお願いします。

添付した画像上部のように、約4万行×1列に約100～200個（各行によって個数はまちまち）の0、1、2のいずれかが並んだデータがあります。
これを、約100～200個の0、1、2の並びを分割して約4万行×100～200列（欠測の要素は#N/Aや-などで表現したいです）のデータに変換したいです。
文字列の並びを1つずつ分割するのに、list()関数が便利そうだったので、以下のようなコードを書きました。

```
import pandas as pd
seg = pd.read_table('segments.txt')

def seg_split(x):
　　return(list(x))

seg_list = seg['segments'].apply(seg_split)
print(seg_list)
```

これによってできたのが、画像下部のようなデータで、データフレームの各要素がリストになっています。
初心者なりに色々調べてみたのですが、この後、リストではなく約4万行×100～200列に変換する手段がわからず困っています。
そもそもリスト化する段取りがよくないのかもしれませんが。[image: 添付ファイル]

Comment: metropolisさん、ありがとうございました。無事できました。Seriesを使えばよかったのですね。スッキリです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NaN` をどうするかはお好みで。

```py
seg_list = seg['segments'].apply(lambda i: pd.Series([*i]))
```